# "Item unavailable in your country" on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

As the title says, I'm getting the error "item unavailable in your country" when trying to test purchase an in-app product. What confuses me is that a couple of days ago it was working fine. You can see in one of the screenshots I was able to successfully purchase a product. Now today I am unable to. Does anyone have any history of this happening? if so what did you do to fix it?[image: Item Unavailable 1] [image: Item unavailable 2]

Comment: Where do you from ? Do you know if this error is only for you or for all the users ?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. It corrected itself after I uploaded a new version. I hadn't upgraded since late April, so I put it down to the fact that the upgrade interval was too long.

Comment: You posted a new update on play store? I just released my app for alpha testing and facing this issue.

Comment: Yes, the update was to the Google Play Store. If you haven't already made any successful purchases, then you may want to check under Price and Availability that you have everything set up correctly. In my case I had finished all my subscription code months ago so wasn't expecting a problem like this to occur. If you think everything is ok, then I'd contact Play support and ask them what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this problem is related to the new Google Play Billing Library 5. Play Billing Library 4 is still meant to be ok, but QuerySkuDetailsAsync is now deprecated and has been replaced by QueryProductDetailsAsync. See https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5 and https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/compatibility.

All my subscriptions in the Play console are showing updated May 2022 and I've not made a change to any subscription for months.

I just tested again with my app and it all appears to be ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the build in the closed track, please ensure that you have accepted the test invitation from the invited email or it will show this error.

**Step 1: Go to Release -> Testing -> Closed Testing**

[image]

**Step 2: Click on Manage Track**

**Step 3: Click on Testers tab**

[image]

**Step 4: Scroll to the bottom and you will see 2 options. Copy the link for the web and open the link in your phone or browser with the test email you want to test.**

[image]

**Step 5: When you open the link you will have an option to Become A Tester. Click on that and then you are good to go.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred again today on a device that I haven't used for a while. I knew that the subscription had expired because when I queried the subscription it failed and the reported exception from Google's servers read "The subscription purchase is no longer available for query because it has been expired for too long." The subscription was purchased on May 10th. From previous testing expired subscriptions for beta testers are still returned for something close to 40 days. At that point, the beta tester then has to purchase a new subscription.

I, therefore, attempted to make a new purchase and got the "Item unavailable in your country" message. The way around that was to use the Google Play link supplied to a beta tester and then reinstall the app directly from Google Play. I was then able to successfully purchase a new subscription.

My conclusion is that Google Play has changed the procedure because I've never had to do that previously when using any of the devices I test with.

Answer (score -1):

Currently also experiencing this bug in a particular game. But works fine in my other games

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).